# Unable to log request payload in jersey rest framework

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to log the request payload in my REST API using jersey rest framework.

```
public class PostPayloadFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
@Context HttpServletRequest tempRequest;
public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest request) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST") || request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("PUT")))
        return request;

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    InputStream in = null;;
    try {
        in = tempRequest.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ReaderWriter.writeTo(in, out);

        byte[] requestEntity = out.toByteArray();
        String payLoad = new String(requestEntity,"UTF-8");
        payLoad = payLoad + "\n";
        payLoad = payLoad.trim();
        request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
        return request;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new ContainerException(ex);
    }

}
```

}

I am trying to log the request in second try catch block. It logs everything but not the payload data that I am setting using

```
request.setEntityInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(requestEntity));
```

The log output:

```
Nov 18, 2015 9:18:30 AMcom.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter filter
INFO: 7 * Server in-bound request
7 > PUT https://localhost/sdkapi/abcdef/0/ghijklmno
7 > host: localhost
7 > user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
7 > accept: application/vnd.nsm.v2.0+json
7 > accept-language: null
7 > accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
7 > sdk-api: N0JDNzFENUIyRBDBBDJJUSJJDJJJDJJZFQkQzNjk6MQ==
7 > content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
7 > content-length: 1148
7 > cookie: JSESSIONID=7BC71D5B2F0357B43607BBA686EBD369
7 > connection: keep-alive
7 >
```

Comment: I'm curious why it isn't already logging the entity as that is the default behavior of the LoggingFilter

Comment: @peeskillet yes, that is what I am trying to figure out. Still no success. Apart from the actual payload everything else is getting logged

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do with your `PostPayloadFilter`. The original `LoggingFilter` already should log it. Are you saying that _without_ your `PostPayloadFilter`, and simply using the `LoggingFilter` is not logging the entity. I have tested, and it always logs the entity. There's a [property you can set](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.9/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/LoggingFilter.html#FEATURE_LOGGING_DISABLE_ENTITY) to disable the logging of the entity but is enabled by default.

Comment: @peeskillet check this http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/d83ca80b1053/java-jersey-logging-request-body-in-tomcat.html. Seems like some issue with tomcat

Comment: Ahh I see. From what I can tell, the work around (filter from the link) actually logs the entity itself.  I don't know if you are expecting that just by doing what you have done above that that will cause the logging filter to log it. I don't think that was the intention of the code from the link.

Comment: In any case, I would imagine the stream from the HttpServletRequest would already have been read by Jersey. You might want to get the stream from the ContainerRequest instead